# replacing all uppercase words by ucword

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am having small problem. I am trying to replace words in sentence i.e.

```
HELLO World WHAT
```

by

```
Hello World What
```

so far have way to detecting it:

```
preg_replace('/(\b[A-Z][A-Z]+\b)/sm','$1', $string);
```

but it does nothing as I can't put as an argument ucwords('$1').

Any help would be great.

cheers,
/Marcin

P.S.
this kind of methods are not good: ucwords(strtolower($string)); as I want to leave all what wasn't all caps as it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is slightly more efficient to use an anonymous function rather then call on the `/e` modifier.

```
   $formatted = preg_replace_callback(
        '/(\b[A-Z][A-Z]+\b)/',
        create_function(
            '$matches',
            'return ucwords(strtolower($matches[0]));'
        ),
        $string
    );
```

Comment: The replacement string is essentially passed into PHP for every replacement, as opposed to the callback method where it only needs to be passed once.

Comment: nice, I have posted other regex question, can you help with that too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177374/detecting-and-replacing-merged-words-myword-to-my-word-php-regex - cheers

Comment: you need to be careful with create function though, if you have lots of rows to process it can go out of allowed memory, so not good for big datasets despite efficiency

Answer (score 2):

How about using:

```
ucwords(strtolower($string));
```

You can combine this approach with the `e` modifier:

```
preg_replace('/(\b[A-Z][A-Z]+\b)/sme','ucwords(strtolower($1))', $string);
```

Comment: That's not the way as somthing what wasn't ALL caps should stay as it was, but thanks

Comment: Modified to use the regexp - should now work on the all caps only.

Comment: But, you're not using the `/e` modifier in that line of code?