# Detecting and replacing merged words MyWord to My Word - PHP, regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a function which is detecting and unmerging two words i.e.

```
HelloWord
```

after function will become

```
Hello World
```

the problem is it will do same to iPhone -> i Phone which is not good, is there a way to replace only if first word is longer than 1

here is my current function (regex):

```
function unseparateWords($string)
{
    $CapRegX = '/(\B[A-Z])(?=[a-z])|(?<=[a-z])([A-Z])/sm';
    $RepStr = ' $1$2';

    return preg_replace($CapRegX,$RepStr,$string);
}
```

thanks for help.

cheers,
/Marcin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could search for the position between a lowercase and an uppercase character

```
(?<=\B[a-z])(?=[A-Z])
```

and replace this "zero-length string" with a space.

```
(?<=\B[a-z]) # assert that we are right after a lowercase ASCII character
             # unless that character is the start of the current word
(?=[A-Z])    # assert that there is an uppercase ASCII character right ahead
```

In PHP:

```
function unseparateWords($string)
{
    return preg_replace('/(?<=\B[a-z])(?=[A-Z])/', ' ', $string);
}
```

Comment: don;t think it will do the trick, can't understand why /(\B[A-Z])(?=[a-z]+)|(?<=[a-z]+)([A-Z])/sm not working

Comment: Why don't you think so? Have you tried it - it works here. As to why your regex doesn't work: One reason is that PHP doesn't support infinite repetition inside lookbehind expressions.

Comment: how should I replace it with patterns in my current function ? - not working that way: /(\B[A-Z])(?=[a-z])|(?<=\B[a-z])(?=[A-Z])/sm - still spliting iPhone to i Phone

Comment: Well, of course it's not working if you're still using the wrong regex. I thought the code sample was clear enough - I have now updated it so you have a ready-made function that you only have to copy and paste into your code.